# how to use ng-class calling a controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 possible data types ('a','b', and 'c') and I have 3 differet classes for them.  The problem is my controller function never gets called.

my CSS

```
.a{
    color: red
}
.b{
    color: blue
}
.c{
    color: green
}
```

my function

```
    this.getClass = function(num){
        console.log("here");
        var returnVal = '';
        if (num <= 1){
                returnVal = 'a'
            }
        else if (num > 1 && num < 10)
            {   returnVal = 'b'
        }
        else{
                returnVal = 'c'
        }
        return returnVal;
    };
```

my html
UPDATED!

```
<tr id="num{{$index}}"
            ng-click="$map[$index] = ! $map[$index]"
            ng-repeat-start="num in currentController.nums"
            ng-class="currentController.getClass($num)">
    <td>num</td>
</tr>
```

according to the ngClass docs listed https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid expression there, since your method returns the string equivalent of class name (Assuming you are correctly using *controller as* syntax and alias is `currentController`) just do:

```
ng-class="currentController.getClass(num)">
```

Example:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as currentController">
//....
<div ng-class="currentController.getClass(num)">Hello</div>
//...
</div>
```

Comment: It should you had a problem which i pointed out. Can you show where is `currentController` ? Where have you specified your controller in the view? For example see my answer. Please do not edit your question to fix the issues based on the answer. With that you are invalidating the answer(s).

Comment: it was the '$' on num... angular is so confusing on when to use $ and when not to

Comment: @MattWestlake you do not have to use `$` unless the variable is prefixed with $ which in your case is not. Generally angular prefixes its special properties with `$` ($index, $first, $on etc..) indicating it is special and added by angular. SO in short use `$` only if the property or variable starts with `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:  `<span ng-class="getClass(num)">Foo</span>`

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fgdY6HX7pEqJzNupzyZN?p=preview)**

Comment: getClass(num) is a function on my controller

Comment: `ng-class` expression should not be with `{{}}`, if you add it, you are taking as a string

Comment: it was the $ on num, see other answer